# Django + Google URL Tracking

Tags: django, google-analytics

First off I'm self taught so please be forgiving if it seems like I'm making an obvious mistake.

The company I work for has just launched its new website, and I am incharge of our email campaigns. The website is built on Django, on an Apache2 server on a Debian machine. When i add the tracking cod to my url like I normally would, django tries to read it as if its all part of the url.

**Example:
(old site)**

*example.com/index.html&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=V12102*

I have looked around to see what i can do to fix this, and have found that I may need to add a '?' in it.

**Examples:
(all of these will load the page, but im not sure if the tracking will still work)**

*example.com/vw/?&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=V12102*

*example.com/vw/?=&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=V12102*

*example.com/vw?&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=V12102/*

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can figure out which one works by inspecting the cookies on the page, or, you can use the Google Analytics tracking code debugger to make sure the URLs you're using work. https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get params start with ? as the separator from the URL. This is not django specific. Your usual method would not work anywhere!

`&` is for separating key/value pairs.

`example.com/vw/?utm_medium=email&key=value&key2=value2` is OK.

Your tracking will work, assuming your view takes in request.GET['utm_medium'] and does something with it :P

When in doubt, throw in some debug code and visit your url yourself (like with print `request.GET`) and see what comes through.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is `*example.com/vw/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=V12102*`.
GET parameters start with a `?` after the URL and are separated by `&`.

Answer (score 0):

This tool should make your life easier:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578

Even when using it, always confirm that the URLs work and there are no redirects which remove the parameters from the URL.